# How to remediate vmImage Error in YAML Pipeline

Tags: python, azure-pipelines, cicd, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-repos

I am trying to set up my first pipeline in Azure DevOps. I set up a YAML pipeline which I want to run anytime someone commits a change to any branch; the yml file I wrote will run a python script which will send a notification to a teams channel with specified information. However, as I'm trying to "queue" my pipeline, I keep getting this error "Unexpected vmImage 'windows-latest,' so my pipeline won't run. I've checked the agent pool/agents and they appear to support windows (I've tried different variations of windows as found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)). I'm stumped on what the issue is here, and how to fix it. This is my yml file:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - '*'

jobs:
- job: RunPythonScript
  displayName: 'Run Python Script'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'  
  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.x'

  - checkout: self 

  - script: |
      pip install -r requirements.txt  
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      pip install -r requirements.txt

      if git diff --name-only $(Build.SourceVersion) $(Build.SourceVersionPrevious) | grep -q '\.json$'; then
          python \\company.com\data\planning\PowerBI\Test Scripts\TeamsNotificationScript.py
      else
          echo "No changes to .json files. Skipping script."
      fi
    displayName: 'Run Python Script'
```

- I checked "agent pools" in Azure and their capabilities for each enabled agent (all Agent.OS values are Windows_NT), so should support 'windows-latest, 2019, 2016, etc.,' which I also tried.
- I'm using the Default agent pool in DevOps and there are multiple agents enabled in the Default agent pool.

Comment: Is that the *exact* error message?

Comment: It is so weird as the same job.pool property `pool: vmImage: 'windows-latest'` works in my pipeline. I am fairly curious how the issue was reproduced from your side. Could you please share the detailed steps with some screenshots of the error to help understand how the pipeline was queued? Was it triggered by simply a commit from any of the branches in your repo? Can you double check the referenced YAML file of this pipeline in the **triggering branch**? Is it the same as that was posted in the topic? By the way, are you able to run a **classic pipeline** on `windows-latest` MS-hosted agent?